# Parse.com - substring search in tokenised array field

Tags: cocoa, full-text-search, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement complex full text search feature on multiple Parse classes at once (query1 on class1 OR query2 on class2, etc.). As per [Parse's](http://blog.parse.com/2013/03/19/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/) recommendation it's better to tokenise the strings and after filtering store it in an Array where one can take advantage of `whereKey:containsAllObjectsInArray:`.

My issue is that:

- it searches for ALL terms instead of ANY
- it doesn't search for substrings (e.g. Parse Array: `["David", "Peter", "Vivien"]`, searching for `vi` returns 0 objects)

As of now it seems that the only "decent" way is to concatenate all strings within the class into one big string and use `whereKey:containsString:`. I'm assuming this will be less efficient than the tokenised method.

Do you guys have any recommendation or suggestions how to develop both - efficient and scalable search over multiple Parse classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full text search is a complex issue, many databases have special support for it that you can turn on after considering the costs... Parse doesn't support full text search.

In regards to doing what you want with parse, `whereKey:equalTo:` will work on an array finding where one of the items match the string supplied.

If you want to match on ANY you can use an [OR query](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-compound/iOS):

```
PFQuery *term1Query = [[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class"] whereKey:@"terms" equalTo:@"David"];
PFQuery *term2Query = [[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class"] whereKey:@"terms" equalTo:@"Peter"];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[term1Query, term2Query]];
```

If you want to be able to match on partial strings, you'll need to change your schema a bit. Create a new Class called "SearchToken" or something, with a "token" column of type string.

Make sure this is always forced to lowercase when creating/updating this. You can then share tokens between related classes (e.g. don't create two "david" tokens, simply link to the existing one on new classes). Force your input to lowercase also, since all string matching is case-sensitive.

Your "terms" column would need to now contain pointers instead of just words.

You can now do a query against your "SearchToken" class and use a `whereKey:matchesQuery:` criteria on your parent class, e.g.:

```
PFQuery *tokenQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SearchToken"];
[tokenQuery whereKey:@"token" containsString:@"vi"];

PFQuery *mainQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyClass"];
[mainQuery whereKey:@"terms" matchesQuery:tokenQuery];
```

You can even use an or query like above with a mixture of full matches and partial matches.

Be aware that the token query might match many rows, and is limited by the 100 row default, consider setting the limit higher if you think you'll need to, the max is 1000.

In regards to creating SearchToken rows, assuming you've already gathered tokens from a string and forced them to lowercase and now have tokens to link/create:

```
// these would be generated, manually creating for demonstration
NSArray *tokens = @[@"david", @"and", @"the", @"lion"];

PFQuery *existingTokens [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SearchToken"];
[existingTokens whereKey:@"token" containedIn:tokens];

// results of the above already exist, create new rows for the remainder
```

There is the issue of a possible race-condition where another device might create a "david" token after the query is run. You could have a job that looks for duplicates and removes duplicate rows, fixing all pointers as it goes... though even there you want to handle race conditions so the logic might be to tag the duplicates and have all other queries search `[query whereKeyDoesNotExist: @"duplicateOf"];` then find all records that point to rows that do point to a duplicate and point them to the `duplicateOf`. All depends how important it is to you to avoid duplicates, perhaps it is a non-issue for you.

Comment: Well, that's a shame. At least I learnt something new. I'll update my answer with an alternate solution instead.

Comment: hm that's interesting... so the SearchToken class then needs to have  5 additional Relation columns (since I want to be able to search content of 5 Classes) to keep the reference to a result Class?

Comment: In that case yes, you could do that and create reverse relationships instead/also. Then your query would find tokens and then query each relation field to get matching classes. Alternatively you could use my sample above to do a `whereKey:matchesQuery:` against each class and re-use the `tokenQuery` without needing to add extra relation columns.

Comment: ok, that should work - last concern goes to building the SearchToken Class. Is there an easy way of checking whether the token already exists (to update Relation) or do I need to query each token separately? - e.g. I have a title of 10 words, after splitting and cleanup I'm left with 5 words I want to put in SearchToken Class.

Comment: great, this looks like a feasible solution. I'll test it out. Thank you Timothy!

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully implemented the search feature with few small modifications. Convincing Parse to perform full text search is quite expensive (saving: 2 API calls: fetch existing tokens + save new tokens, searching: 1 + (1 * N): fetching tokens matching search terms + N == no of searchable objects). **I wonder if there's better way of achieving the same result, anybody has any suggestions on how to improve the cost?**

While saving is quite the same as Timothy described, retrieving is as follows:

```
// 1)   check for sanitised terms in SearchToken class
//      _marrInputTokens - mutable array of sanitised search terms
NSMutableArray *_marrInnerQueries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *_token in _marrInputTokens)
{
    PFQuery *_innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SearchToken"];
    [_innerQuery whereKey:@"token" containsString:_token];
    [_marrInnerQueries addObject:_innerQuery];
}

PFQuery *_pSearchTokenQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:_marrInnerQueries];
[_pSearchTokenQuery setLimit:1000];
[_pSearchTokenQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *tokenObjects, NSError *error) {
    if(error)
    {
        QLog([error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        // 2)   if not all search terms (even as substrings) were found in SearchToken, no need to search further
        //      as no object can meet the search criteria and we can save some calls
        if([tokenObjects count] >= [_marrInputTokens count])
        {

            // 3) all search terms were found in SearchToken 
            // fetch all SearchableObject_1 corresponding objects
            PFQuery *_pResultQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SearchableObject_1"];

            // 4) need to make sure all tokens are conjugated with AND operator
            for(PFObject *_tokenObject in _marrSearchTokenResults)
            {
                [_pResultQuery whereKey:@"searchIndex" equalTo:_tokenObject];
            }

            // 5) pagination (adding setSkip: for real pagination)
            [_pResultQuery setLimit:PARSE_RESULT_LIMIT];
            [_pResultQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

                if(error)
                {
                    QLog([error localizedDescription]);
                }
                else
                {
                    // 6) objects contains all matching entries for SearchableObject_1

                    // 7) nested additional SearchableObject_x searches
                    // ....
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```